# If $f:(X,d) \rightarrow (Y,d^{\prime})$ is an surjective isometry , then

Tags: general-topology

Show that if $$f:(X,d) \rightarrow (Y,d^{\prime})$$ is an surjective isometry then for any $x,y \in X$ we have $$f(E_d(x,z))=E_{d^{\prime}}(f(x),f(z))$$
Recall that for any metric space $(X,d)$ and $x,z \in X,$ then the equality set for $x,z$ is $$E_d(x,z)= \{ y \in X : d(x,z) = d(x,y)+d(y,z) \} $$ For the L.H.S. we have (going to stop writing 'E')
$$f(E_d(x,z)) = f(d(x,y))+f(d(y,z))$$ $$=f(x-y)+f(y-z)$$
$$f(x)-f(y) +f(y)-f(z)$$ $$=f(x)-f(z)$$ $$=E_{d^{\prime}}(f(x),f(z)).$$

I am relatively confident in my solution. Three problems I am curious about. I have generalized the metrics to simply be the difference between two points in the image and two points in the pre-image of my map. Is this possible? Also, I have shown (I believe) that the left hand side equals the right hand side. Do I need to do the same for the right hand side? Finally, do I need to say more about why the map is linear (if it is)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your solution doesn't make a lot of sense. If $x,y\in X$ then $d(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}$, so in most cases it doesn't make sense to talk about $f(d(x,y))$. It is also not correct to assume $d(x,y)=x-y$. Even if subtraction is defined on your space this is not a metric.

Let us assume $a\in f(E_d(x,z))$. Then $a=f(y)$ where $y\in E_d(x,z)$, so $d(x,z)=d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. Since $f$ is an isometry, we have $d'(f(x),f(z))=d'(f(x),f(y))+d'(f(y),f(z))$, so $a=f(y)\in E_{d'}(f(x),f(z))$. This shows $f(E_d(x,z))\subseteq E_{d'}(f(x),f(y))$.

Suppose now $a\in E_{d'}(f(x),f(z))$. Since $f$ is surjective, $a=f(y)$ for some $y\in X$, and we have $d'(f(x),f(z))=d'(f(x),f(y))+d'(f(y),f(z))$. Applying the isometry property once again we have $d(x,z)=d(x,y)+d(y,z)$, so $y\in E_d(x,z)$, and hence $a=f(y)\in f(E_d(x,z))$. This shows $E_{d'}(f(x),f(z))\subseteq f(E_d(x,z))$, completing the proof.

Comment: Thank you. I searched all through my notes trying to see how in the world $f(d(x,y))$ would even look!